# Set Additional Include Directories in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I am using Qt Creator to rewrite my former project which is developed in Visual Studio. In this project I need to use an external library (gloox for xmpp).

Here's what I did in Visual Studio:

1. Add c:/dir1/ to the Additional Include Directories, that's where the tons of .h and .cpp files are.
2. Add c:/dir2/ in the linker setting, that's where the .lib file is.

I want to do the same thing in Qt Creator, so I added INCLUDEPATH += c:/dir1/ to the end of my .pro file, but when I qmaked again I still could not include anything from dir1 successfully.

```
#include <message.h>
```

C1083: Cannot open include file: 'message.h': No such file or directory

What should I do?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem... Could you please show the _full_ output of qmake, as well as nmake VERBOSE=1 and preferably also the full project file?

Comment: Is it possible that your dir1 contains spaces? In that case, you would need to escape or quote, but it is hard to tell without the qmake output, et al.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I spent a whole day and finally solved it. Believe it or not, here is my solution: copy everything in the .pro file and delete the .pro file. Then create a new .pro file and copy everything back, then qmake then run. I want to kill myself now......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment discussion, the problem seems to be that, after the `INCLUDEPATH` and potentially other relevant modifications, you forgot to properly re-run qmake.

This is necessary when dealing with QtCreator unfortunately due to the following long-standing issue:

[Creator should know when to rerun qmake](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-231)

Comment: I think I have re-runed qmake: by Build->run qmake in Qt Creator, and qmake in the command line. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: qmake is not enough if you have subdirectories. In that case, you would need to use `qmake -r` to be recursive. It might be that you did not properly re-run qmake, or in a wrong folder, not recursively, etc.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this. I think my problem is that I took it for granted that Qt Creator choose the proper way automatically. I'll check out the parameter settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: copy everything in the .pro file and delete the .pro file. Then create a new .pro file and copy everything back, then execute qmake then run.

Comment: You simply forgot to re-run qmake properly. It is not about copy and deletion. That just triggered the re-run. See my answer for details.